# React TypeError when Passing Boolean Parameter to Custom Hook: Minified Error #31

Tags: reactjs

Added a last Boolean parameter, but it raise an error when calling it, why?

```
react-dom.production.min.js:152 Uncaught Error: Minified React error #31; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=31&args[]=object%20with%20keys%20%7B%7D for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
```

```
export default function useLocalStorage<T>(
    key: string,
    fallbackValue: T,
    skipLoadStoredValue?: Boolean
): [T | null, SetValue<T | null>] {
```

```
const [teamSlugUser, setTeamSlugUser] = useLocalStorageTX2<string>(
        'teamSlugUser',
        teamSlugUserFallback,
        true
    )
```